# Which android sdk packages are required to be installed and which are not required ? Are all versions of android API required to be installed?

Tags: android, eclipse

I just installed the android apk and adt plugin for eclipse. Further in the sdk manager , I've installed all the tools , Android 4.4.2(API 19) , Android 2.1(API 7) as well as the android support library and google USB driver. Now what i want to know about is , are these packages enough to start development or am i still missing everything ?

Further what i want to know is, if i want my app to be compatible with all android versions , do i need to install all versions of Android API ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This should be enough.
2. No, you just need the newest SDK, set the build target to that API version and all lower versions will be supported. For keeping backwards-compatibility, you'll also have to make sure to use APIs that are supported on the lowest SDK version you want to support

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **You only have to install the ones you want to develop for.**

My advice in to install at least the 5 most common ones to be able to test your app against these version. 
You probably want your app to be also available for users which didn't yet update to Android 4.4.2.